# Flyway reports success even though database gave warnings

Tags: flyway

We are using Flyway 4 (great tool!) on Oracle.

When invalid DDL is committed, the continuous database build breaks.. and all the team gets an email.. all good so far.

But when, code that breaks one of our stored procedures is committed.. ie procedure gets created, but it fails to compile.. we still get a *successful* migration reported from Flyway.

During the migration we see something like :

`DB: Warning: execution completed with warning (SQL State: 99999 - Error Code: 17110)`

..but still the Flyway ant task reports success.

As we have a lot of stored procedures, 9 times out of 10 it is these that are broken by developers, and not the DDL. We **really** would like Flyway to fail on a warning also. Can anyone advise how best to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Found an acceptable solution for us and implemented it as follows, utilising Flyways callback mechanism which is documented on the Flyway website.

There are many callbacks available and are invoked at various points, but the one that appears to suit our needs is `afterMigrate`. In the callback, we can execute sql (on Oracle) which counts the number of invalid objects in the user schema at hand

So, implementing a java `afterMigrate` callback as follows does the job:

```
    public void afterMigrate(Connection connection) {
    String countInvalidObjs = "select count(*) " +
                              "from user_objects " +
                              "where object_type in ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY','TRIGGER') " + 
                              "and status = 'INVALID' ";
    int invalidObjCount = -1;
    Statement statement;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(countInvalidObjs);
        while (rs.next()) {
            invalidObjCount = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("*error* " + t.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if(invalidObjCount!=0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fail to complete migration, build finished with databse warnings");
        }
    }
}
```